Firebase A/B Remote Config Testing Against App Versions, not parameter in a single version
I want to do A/B testing of my two versions of android app. I want to set my two app versions as my variants. Can I do that? and how? Firebase is giving me options for A/B testing only on events, not specifically against two versions. Can we do that?
I tried finding it, but couldn't find A/B testing of versions.

Have you thought about A/B testing using a flag on the remote configuration to enable/disable the feature you want to A/B test? I wrote an article about it.

I feel it doesn't make much sense to set app versions as variants since you can implement differently in those versions. For instance, you can make a button blue in version A and red in version B.

I have to test my revenue in both app versions as I have changed overall in-app strategies in both versions.
